# Understanding the ffmpeg decoder format

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg, I get this output (2 different examples)

```
Input #0, au, from 'c:\TestFiles\sample.au':
  Duration: 00:02:02.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16be ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
---
Input #0, wav, from 'c:\TestFiles\sample.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:02:02.09, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
```

I understand what the `pcm_s16be` part means, but what is the information that follows that in parenthesis, e.g., `([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003)`?  I can't find any documentation that explains it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[3][0][0][0] / 0x0003` <-- these are codec tags.

The hex value on the right is the raw value as stored (usually little-endian); the format on the left is the literary representation. Usually if it's printable characters, that will be shown e.g. `mp4a` else the decimal number in square brackets.